# xml file is not properly showed per style sheet

Tags: xml, stylesheet

I am very new person for XML file... please understand even-though my question is so easy.

I've created xml file as below, however the xml files is not properly showed. 
It does not appear as a stylesheet and only the input data is displayed.

What is the problem and What needs to be corrected to display the data for the stylesheet?
Thank you in advance for your help.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE fda-regional:fda-regional SYSTEM "http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional-v3-3.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/static/eCTD/us-regional.xsl"?>
<fda-regional:fda-regional dtd-version="3.3" xml:lang="text" xmlns:fda-regional="http://www.ich.org/fda" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
 <admin>
  <applicant-info>
   <id>123456677</id>
   <company-name>ABCDE</company-name>
   <applicant-contacts>
    <applicant-contact>
<!--applicant-contact-type "fdaact1" is regulatory -->
     ......
    </applicant-contact>
    <applicant-contact>
     .....
    </applicant-contact>
   </applicant-contacts>
  </applicant-info>
  <application-set>
   <application application-containing-files="true">
    <application-information>
<!-- application-type "fdaat4" is IND -->
     <application-number application-type="fdaat4">123456</application-number>
    </application-information>
    <submission-information>
<!-- submission-type "fdast1" is original-application -->
     <submission-id submission-type="fdast1">0001</submission-id>
<!-- submission-sub-type "fdasst3" is application -->
     <sequence-number submission-sub-type="fdasst3">0000</sequence-number>
<!-- form-type "fdaft1" is Form FDA 1571 -->     
    </submission-information>
   </application>
  </application-set>
 </admin>
 <m1-regional>
  ......
 </m1-regional>
</fda-regional:fda-regional>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing obviously wrong with the XML, but the XML is the only thing you've shown us. That means it's either the stylesheet, or the way you are running it.

The stylesheet looks like tested production-quality code, though it does use the private `msxsl:script` element which may mean there are restrictions on how it is run (which environments/processors).

I assume you're running the code in the browser. It could well be a cross-site scripting issue; browsers are very cautious these days about where the XML and XSL can be loaded from.

A couple of things to try:

(a) Look at the diagnostic logs in the browser's development console. Very often it tells you exactly what's wrong.

(b) Make sure you access both the XML document and the XSLT stylesheet using HTTP (not file acccess) and from the same web server (make a copy of the stylesheet on you own web server).